# Comparing two dichotomous variables (non-paired)

Tags: binary-data, independence

I would like to compare two dichotomous variables:

1. pass/fail for a statistics test before statistics class (pre-test)
2. pass/fail for a statistics test after statistics class (post-test)

I only have data on pass/fail (so dichotomous and not able to retrieve interval measure; therefore not able to execute a dependent t-test)
As my fellow students filled in the test anonymously I am not able to pair/match results of the pre-test and post-test (so I am not able to execute a McNemar Test).

Does anyone know which statistical test would be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of analyzing such data is to set up a $2\times 2$ [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) and to run either [Pearson's $\chi^2$ test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) or [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) on it. Your favorite statistics software will have tools for this. For instance, in R you can use `table()` and `chisq.test()`.

Comment: Dear Stephan, thank you for your reply! I was hesitating if I indeed could use a Pearson's χ2 test. At least expected frequencies are greater than 5. However as the same group was tested two times, I don't know if my data meets the assumption of the chi-square test about independence of data?

Comment: Well, we always come from some underlying population, so that would be fine. The fact that your *individuals* were tested twice, but you don't know how to tie the two measurements from a single individual together, is a little bit more concerning. But to be honest, I would not expect the impact in terms of the significance of the learning outcome to be major. Here is a proposal: try simulating different matches of pre- and post-responses (e.g., random, or with a given correlation), then run McNemar each time, and see how much the results differ from a simple Fisher's test.

Comment: Dear Stephan, thank you very much for your response. Your proposal seems like a good solution to me. Thank you for thinking along!